# I cant import stripe package to my IDE (Pycharm)

Tags: python, api, package

I installed stripe (pip install --upgrade stripe) via terminal and it seems to install successfully. but I can't import stripe (import stripe) in Pycharm.
I'm new to python please help me with this. thanks

Comment: You are probably running an virtual environment inside Pycharm, so you need to install `stripe` inside that venv.

Comment: please check the current interpreter you are using File -> Settings -> Project -> Project interpreter